# How to find N circles with minimum radius r could cover a specific region?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

The formal description would be:

Given a specific region $A\subset R^2$, and a fixed number N, how to find a point set $S = \{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ that minimize

$\sup_{(x,y)\in A}\min_{1\le j\le N}\sqrt{(x_j-x)^2+(y_j-y)^2}$

An approximate algorithm to find those points is also acceptable (but simply picking "grid points" may not be a good option).

Thanks!

Comment: Can $A$ be anything, or does $A$ has some extra properties?

Comment: @SimonMarynissen A could be anything, e.g. circles, squares or weird shapes.  But basically it is "continuous" (sorry I do not know how to say this formally, what I mean is A is not a set of weird discrete points with "bad" mathematical properties).

Comment: This sort of problem is known as clustering. You can find a detailed explanation on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Vik78  Thanks for pointing this out!  But how may we cluster infinite number of points in data set A?

Comment: You don't cluster an infinite amount of points. Your set is specifically finite. Hence fixed number $N$. you might want to find the limit as $N \to \infty$ but that would be very odd indeed. And if you want to do that. then you find the density points where your set converges and place covers around them.

Comment: Yeah, there's no real way to give an algorithm to solve the clustering problem if the data set is infinite. Perhaps you can solve it in special cases when the set is infinite, or you can approximate infinite sets as limits of finite ones.